# How to add font color to a .net console app?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

Is there a way to color the font of certain lines in a console app in .net?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.foregroundcolor.aspx

You can change the foreground and background colors of the console. The foreground color is of course the text.

Answer (score 18):

```
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
```