# c# Console app | Writeline with 2 colors?

Tags: c#, colors, console-application, console.writeline

I am learning C# and i am writing a text based game.

I would like to know if its possible to have 1 line of code (Console.WriteLine method) but outputs a message from my game with the players given name with a different color so it kinda highlights it.

This is my current simple  code for the message:

```
Console.WriteLine("Can you survive, {0}?", player.GetName(); //player.Getname() just returns the name of the user
```

This asks the user for his name:

```
        string name = null;
        string input = null;
        Console.WriteLine("Before you can start your journey, you will have to enter your name.");


        while(input != "Y") 
        {
            if( input == null || input == "N" )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name and press enter:");
                name = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Your name is {0}",name);
            Console.WriteLine("Is this correct? (y/n)");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            input = input.ToUpper();
        }
```

I could only find one answer to this but that is an answer from 2 years ago.. so maybe it is changed?

Thanks in advance if you know the answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14792066/327083

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5299790/327083

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7524057/327083

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6859483/327083

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%23]+console+color

Comment: I agree with J...'s unstated point. This is pretty silly. A quick look in the documentation (or IntelliSense, or Google, or whatever) would have revealed the `ForegroundColor` and `BackgroundColor` properties. It is often faster to spend a few moments helping yourself before posting a question.

Comment: @CodyGray What do you mean... "unstated"?  ;)